# How to pin down the complex integral?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am working with the following problem:

Find the Fourier transformation of the function 
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}.$$
I did not learn any trick in complex analysis (especially various integration theorems), and hence I attempted the following way: Let 
$$I(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-ix\xi}\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}\,\mathrm{d} x,$$
and differentiate under the integral sign to arrive at
$$I'(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-ix\xi}\cdot \sin x\,\mathrm{d} x\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
that is, we need to pin down the Fourier transformation of the sine function. If that function is not very complicated, then we can get $I(\xi)$ by integration. My question is how to integrate (1)? I tried to write $e^{-ix\xi}=\cos(x\xi)+i\sin(x\xi)$ and integrate the real and imaginary parts respectively, but it seems that when we take the two extremes $-\infty$ and $\infty$ to compute the final answer (by fundamental theorem of calculus), the convergence is a problem...

Can anyone give me some hint on that? Is it possible to avoid using any knowledge about complex analysis? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the integral you get  (of $\exp(- i x \xi) \sin x$) does not converge, so that approach does not work. To compute the fourier transform of $\sin x/x$ the trick is usually to compute the Fourier transform of the rectangular wave form (which is the sinc function), and then to note that Fourier transform is essentially an involution. See, for example, [these lecture notes.](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/ft.pdf)